# ¿Como puedo acceder a una clase con partial class en COSMOS?

Tags: c#, string, class, static, os

Estoy creando mi sistema operativo en COSMOS (RaxOS) [Codigo en GitHub](https://github.com/RayElProOficial/RaxOS)

He creado una class llamada `RaxOS.Programs.ProgramHelper.Program` y en mi codigo de la app (scif.cs) tengo esto:`internal partial class scif : Program` pero al escribir `AppName = scif;` me dice: IDE1007 ´El nombre AppName no existe en el contexto actual`. cuando en mi Program.cs (RaxOS.Program.ProgramHelper.Program) tengo esto:

```
public static string AppName;
static int mv;
static int sv;
static int cv;
static int rv;
...
```

Comment: porque no podes heredar las cosas estaticas.. tenes que accederlas en el padre...

Answer (score 0):

Estas asignado un valor a una variable fuera de un método, constructor o propiedad, y eso solo puedes hacerlo cuando declaras la variable

Básicamente estas haciendo lo mismo que:

```
class UnaClase{
  int algo;
  algo=2; //ERROR, no puedes asignar la variable aquí
}
```

Para sobrescribirla puedes hacer:

```
internal partial class scif : Program
{
   public static new string AppName = "scif";
}
```

Pero con este método `scif.AppName` será distinto a `Program.AppName`

---

Me parece, que tu problema de fondo está en un mal entendimiento de la programación orientada a objetos.

Tienes `clases` que es basicamente un tipo, y `objetos` que es una instancia de esa clase.

El modificador `static` dice que lo modificado pertenece a la clase (no al objeto) y **será común para todos los objetos de esa clase**, es decir si se modifica se modifica para todos.

Ciertamente puedes heredar todos los `static` del padre, pero al modificar estos elementos, ya sea desde el hijo o desde el padre, se modificaran ambos, lo cual (en mi opinión) carece de uso práctico. Y si te fijas estas haciendo lo mismo que crear una clase estática, y en una clase estática no puede heredar.

Te recomiendo quitar los elementos `static` de tus clases `scif`, `Program`, `notepad`, etc